# Skype API for video calling

Tags: c#, asp.net, skype

I am using skype api to make a video call from a window application:

(1). when the user is not loggged in to skype on our side (caller side) it is giving error "Wait timeout"

(2). and if we are already logged in to skype and the called person answers the call application gets crashed.

My code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string SkypeID = string.Empty;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_skypecall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SkypeID = txt_skypeID.Text.Trim();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SkypeID))
        {
            try
            {
                Skype skype;

                skype = new Skype("Skype4COM.Skype", "Skype_");

                if (!skype.Client.IsRunning)
                {
                    skype.Client.Start(false, false);
                }

                skype.Attach(5, true);

                skype.CallStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_CallStatusEventHandler(skype_CallStatus);

                Call call = skype.PlaceCall(SkypeID);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Please enter SkypeId ", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }

    static void skype_CallStatus(Call pCall, TCallStatus Status)
    {
        if (Status == TCallStatus.clsInProgress && pCall.PartnerHandle == SkypeID)
        {
            pCall.StartVideoSend();
        }
    }


}
```

How to resolve these two problems? Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell the exception you get when application crashes?

Comment: @James when skype is running but user is not logged in then it throws exceprion "COM Exception was unhandled: Not attached"

Comment: @pwn Can Tell me Exactly where is Crashing 2 Case